# Are Interactive Puzzles on topic?

Tags: discussion

I don't see why they wouldn't be, infact they might never be used even with this question, but are they?

Comment: What do you mean by interactive puzzle?

Comment: @Emrakul Well... It's a puzzle... It's interactive... What more can I say? What do you need clarified?

Comment: @Emrakul What don't you understand?

Comment: I'm honestly just not sure what you mean by 'interactive puzzle.' Is it a puzzle we guess answers to? Something we have to actually have in front of us and fiddle with? Something that we have to fiddle with online? Or...?

Comment: For example let's use the 15 puzzle, a puzzle where you can actually slide the pieces, where you have to solve and post how to do it.

Comment: @warspyking I don't believe there's a way to embed an interactive puzzle into a question. As such, you'd have to either reference a well-known puzzle or link to an external site. I feel like the former would be on topic, but I don't know about the latter.

Comment: @Robb Watts I believe that it IS possible. I'm pretty sure you can embed it in.

Comment: @Robb Go to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox and find the Towers of Hanoi (3rd last to the bottom)

Comment: @warspyking You can add .gifs, but no, you can't embed an interactive puzzle. Just because you believe something doesnt mean it becomes true for everyone else. Just accept that there's no way to embed an interactive puzzle.

Comment: @thin I'll have to check it out.

Comment: @thin You may not have browser/system requirements but check these out: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?2

Comment: Is a puzzle on-topic if it requires you to run JavaScript code to make it interactive?