# Proposal for an an interactive puzzle or type of puzzle - on topic?

Tags: discussion

I am aware of the following but it appears to focus on embedded interactivity which is different from my suggestion. [Are Interactive Puzzles on topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1468/are-interactive-puzzles-on-topic)?

---

My proposal is for a puzzle that is similar to the traditional Hangman but with added elements and for multiplayers.  For example, people take it in turns to guess letters which are then filled in by me.

There is more to it than that in a puzzling sense, but here I simply want to focus on the interactivity.

1. A player takes a guess. It is made in a comment.
2. I either (1) accept the guess and fill in the appropriate blank(s), awarding the player an upvote or (2) I deny the guess and there is no penalty.
3. I personally enforce turn-taking by means of a simple protocol that is clearly set out in advance.
4. The game does not require participants to be present for any specific period of time. Turns take as long as they take, just as in, say, the old idea of playing chess by snail-mail. Anyone can join in or drop out at any time. The main bottle-neck is my availability. I anticpate being able to update things regularly throughout the day. Of course the longest gap would be when I am sleeping.

The advantages of this are

(a) It encourages puzzlers to co-operate in solving a puzzle

(b) It could be fun

What do you think? Is there any reason it could be considered off-topic?

Both encouragement and constructive criticism are welcome.

Comment: If you think it would be fun, I'd suggest giving it a whirl with the semi-interactive puzzle tag, but that wouldn't guarantee it would stay open because it might not be considered on-topic. Still, worth a shot, right?

Comment: Answers are a major part of the site. What role would answers have in your puzzle? And the comments will get messy pretty quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting idea, but perhaps not a good match for the Q&A format of this site.

I can see it working on a threaded discussion forum.

You could give it a try in p.se chat maybe? That could work.

Answer (score 2):

> ### I would give this proposal a definite **no**.

Not because the idea is in itself bad - it could be a lot of fun - but because SE is simply the wrong platform for it. We *are* already on the brink of being the black sheep and what you suggest would put it over the edge.

I like AE's suggestion of trying such *games* (not puzzles) in the chat - if the aim is the "harvest" the community here - but it might be even better to just do it *elsewhere* and tell people about it here in the meta-forum. If any of these *elsewhere* placed puzzles is a really tough nut to crack or otherwise spectacular, you can then bring it additionally to the P.SE site following the general rules we've established here.

*Where* could such a puzzle-game be hosted? I think any facebook, google+ or similar social network site is *much more* suited than P.SE.

Comment: I'm interested in the black-sheep comment. Is this a general impression you have or is it based on some measurable statistic? Where and how is black-sheepness decided?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Its based on the turmoil (or maybe just storm in the water glass) the site last November. While we *evolved* into the site we are now, it never was a 100% vote. I'm very supportive of the current format of the site, but I think it has 'deviated' enough from the original SE concept. As in my answer: Some things just have better fitting sites. If you're interested in my view of what P.SE should be, you may f.e. read [this post on meta](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3190/close-reason-no-permanent-value).